# Processing dir of text files

Tags: powershell

I have a directory of text files that I am trying to process, exclude, copy, and combine. I am trying to copy all the text files in the last day to a temp folder excluding text files based on a unique string found in the text file. I can't come up with a good way to exclude the text files and copy the correct text files to a temp directory.

```
$excludematch = "unique: string","unique: string2"

    foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $dir\*.txt) {
            if ($i.CreationTime -gt ($(Get-Date).AddHours(-24))) {
                if (Get-Content $i.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $stringmatch){ ...do something with matched files... }}}
#combine all text files in the temp folder into a text file named for that day
Get-Content -path $temp_copy\*.txt | Set-Content -path $output\$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt
```

This is kind of what I was thinking to get the list of files I want to exclude. I don't want to remove the files but I don't want them into the combined text file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Break the problem to smaller parts and ask a question about the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to directly forward the filtered txt files to one File for the day you could do it like this:

```
$excludematch = "unique: string","unique: string2"

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $dir\*.txt) {
  if ($i.CreationTime -gt ($(Get-Date).AddHours(-24))) {
    if (!(Get-Content $i.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $excludematch)){
      Get-Content $i.FullName | Out-File -Append -FilePath ".\$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt"
    }}}
```

If you want to do the extra step and put all filtered files into a seperate folder before creating the final .txt, you can do it like this:

```
$excludematch = "unique: string","unique: string2"

foreach ($i in Get-ChildItem $dir\*.txt) {
  if ($i.CreationTime -gt ($(Get-Date).AddHours(-24))) {
    if (!(Get-Content $i.FullName | Select-String -Pattern $excludematch)){
      Copy-Item $i -Destination $tmpPath
    }}}
foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem $tmpPath){
  Get-Content $item.FullName | Out-File -Append -FilePath "D:\tmp\$(get-date -f MM-dd-yyyy).txt"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I used both options.